# Econometric or statistical method to range variables that explain dependant variable

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, methodology

I want to discuss the degree of explanation of my dependant variable $y$ by some independant variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. I want to be able to say that variable $x_1$ explains for example 10% of variation of dependant variable, $x_2$,  5% etc.. The goal is to range variable that explain more my dependant variable to variable that explain less. Is there any econometric method or statistic strategy to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I personally would use the "leave-one-out" technique as follows: first make a regression using all variables and determine the R-squared value. Then repeatedly perform the regression, each time leaving one of the independent variables out of the regression to determine the change in R-squared. I would use the R-squared value as it is commonly held to be the fraction of the dependent data variance explained by the regression model.